Model parameters are not updating for every epoch
I want to compute the gradient norm for every epoch, but when I add the qml.grad function, the model parameters get fixed. I tried different optimizers, but the problem persists.
main.py
    opt = qml.AdamOptimizer(0.05)

    '''load mnist data'''
    data_train,label_train, data_valid, label_valid, data_test, label_test = load_mnist_data()
    # data_train,label_train, data_valid, label_valid, data_test, label_test = load_iris_data()
    # data_train,label_train, data_valid, label_valid, data_test, label_test = load_medmnist_data()

    '''train'''
    best_params = train_fn(model, data_train, label_train, data_valid, label_valid, records,opt, args.epochs)

utilis.py

    def train_fn(model, data_train, label_train, data_valid, label_valid, records, opt, epochs):
        best_acc = 0
        barren_threshold = 1e-5
        best_params = None
    
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # Training step
            print("Parameters before step:", model.params)
            model.params = opt.step(lambda params: cost_fn(params, model, data_train, label_train, records), model.params)
            print("Parameters after step:", model.params)
    
            # Calculate the cost (loss)
            loss = cost_fn(model.params, model, data_train, label_train, records)
    
            # Compute the gradient of the cost function
            grad_fn = qml.grad(cost_fn)
            gradients = grad_fn(model.params, model, data_train, label_train, records)
    
            # Compute the total gradient norm
            total_norm = 0
            for g in gradients:
                param_norm = np.linalg.norm(g)
                total_norm += param_norm ** 2
    
            total_norm = total_norm ** 0.5
    
            if (epoch + 1) % 2 == 0:
                print(f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{epochs}], Loss: {loss}, Gradient Norm: {total_norm}')


